# Why I get "temporary value dropped while borrowed" if I assign, but not when passing via function?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership, borrowing

I am quite fresh with Rust. I have experience mainly in C and C++.

This code from lol_html crate example works.

```
use lol_html::{element, HtmlRewriter, Settings};

let mut output = vec![];

{
    let mut rewriter = HtmlRewriter::try_new(
        Settings {
            element_content_handlers: vec![
                // Rewrite insecure hyperlinks
                element!("a[href]", |el| {
                    let href = el
                        .get_attribute("href")
                        .unwrap()
                        .replace("http:", "https:");

                    el.set_attribute("href", &href).unwrap();

                    Ok(())
                })
            ],
            ..Settings::default()
        },
        |c: &[u8]| output.extend_from_slice(c)
    ).unwrap();

    rewriter.write(b"<div><a href=").unwrap();
    rewriter.write(b"http://example.com>").unwrap();
    rewriter.write(b"</a></div>").unwrap();
    rewriter.end().unwrap();
}

assert_eq!(
    String::from_utf8(output).unwrap(),
    r#"<div><a href="https://example.com"></a></div>"#
);
```

But if I move element_content_handlers vec outside and assign it, I get

> temporary value dropped while borrowed

for the let line:

```
use lol_html::{element, HtmlRewriter, Settings};

let mut output = vec![];

{
    let handlers = vec![
                // Rewrite insecure hyperlinks
                element!("a[href]", |el| {
                    let href = el
                        .get_attribute("href")
                        .unwrap()
                        .replace("http:", "https:");

                    el.set_attribute("href", &href).unwrap();

                    Ok(())
                }) // this element is deemed temporary
            ];

    let mut rewriter = HtmlRewriter::try_new(
        Settings {
            element_content_handlers: handlers,
            ..Settings::default()
        },
        |c: &[u8]| output.extend_from_slice(c)
    ).unwrap();

    rewriter.write(b"<div><a href=").unwrap();
    rewriter.write(b"http://example.com>").unwrap();
    rewriter.write(b"</a></div>").unwrap();
    rewriter.end().unwrap();
}

assert_eq!(
    String::from_utf8(output).unwrap(),
    r#"<div><a href="https://example.com"></a></div>"#
);
```

I think that the method takes ownership of the vector, but I don't understand why it does not work with the simple assignment. I don't want to let declare all elements first. I expect that there is a simple idiom to make it own all elements.

EDIT:
Compiler proposed to bind the element before the line, but what if I have a lot of elements? I would like to avoid naming 50 elements for example. Is there a way to do this without binding all the elements? Also why the lifetime of the temporary ends there inside of vec! invocation in case of a let binding, but not when I put the vec! inside newly constructed struct passed to a method? The last question is very important to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I first tried to reproduce your issue, I got that `try_new` didn't exist. It's been removed in the latest version of lol_html. Replacing it with `new`, your issue didn't reproduce. I was able to reproduce with v0.2.0, though. Since the issue had to do with code generated by macros, I tried `cargo expand` (something you need to install, [see here](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand)).

Here's what `let handlers = ...` expanded to in v0.2.0:

```
let handlers = <[_]>::into_vec(box [(
    &"a[href]".parse::<::lol_html::Selector>().unwrap(),
    ::lol_html::ElementContentHandlers::default().element(|el| {
        let href = el.get_attribute("href").unwrap().replace("http:", "https:");
        el.set_attribute("href", &href).unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }),
)]);
```

and here's what it expands to in v0.3.0

```
let handlers = <[_]>::into_vec(box [(
    ::std::borrow::Cow::Owned("a[href]".parse::<::lol_html::Selector>().unwrap()),
    ::lol_html::ElementContentHandlers::default().element(|el| {
        let href = el.get_attribute("href").unwrap().replace("http:", "https:");
        el.set_attribute("href", &href).unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }),
)]);
```

Ignore the first line, it's how the macro vec! expands. The second line shows the difference in what the versions generate. The first takes a borrow of the result of parse, the second takes a Cow::Owned of it. (Cow stands for copy on write, but it's more generally useful for anything where you want to be generic over either the borrowed or owned version of something.).

So the short answer is the macro used to expand to something that wasn't owned, and now it does. As for why it worked without a separate assignment, that's because Rust automatically created a temporary variable for you.

> When using a value expression in most place expression contexts, a temporary unnamed memory location is created initialized to that value and the expression evaluates to that location instead, except if promoted to a static

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#tempora...

Initially rust created multiple temporaries for you, all valid for the same-ish scope, the scope of the call to try_new. When you break out the vector to its own assignment the temporary created for element! is only valid for the scope of the vector assignment.

I took a look at the [git blame](https://github.com/cloudflare/lol-html/commit/e0eaf6c4234af855d3b77e6cb1731f5f33d0d6fb) for the element! macro in lol_html, and they made the change because someone opened an issue with essentially your problem. So I'd say this is a bug in a leaky abstraction, not an issue with your understanding of rust.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a good write up about such intricacies like Cow::Owned? Was there a way to wrap every element in something to make it work with the old version? Basically was there a way to make a named vec in a single statement with unnamed elements?

Comment: @HadrianWęgrzynowski In terms of Cow, it's an optimization to allow you to avoid a clone. It basically holds something that's either owned or borrowed. You can get a reference to the contents trivially either way, and if you ask it for an owned value it will noop in the owned case and clone in the borrowed case. With the old version the solution would have been to file a bug report, their macro was just wrong. You can make a named vec with unnamed elements, you just can't make a named vec with temporary references.

Comment: @HadrianWęgrzynowski https://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-fizzbuzz/ and https://fasterthanli.me/articles/working-with-strings-in-rust

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a temporary value inside the vector (`element`). This means that the value created inside of the vector only exists for that fleeting lifetime inside of the vector. At the end of the vector declaration, that value is freed, meaning that it no longer exists. This means that the value created inside `vec![]` only exists for that fleeting lifetime inside of `vec![]`. At the end of `vec![]`, the value is freed, meaning that it no longer exists:

```rust
let handlers = vec![
 ______
|  
|    element!("a[href]", |el| {
|        let href = el.get_attribute("href").unwrap().replace("http:", |"https:");
|        el.set_attribute("href", &href).unwrap();
|        Ok(())
|    }),
|______ ^ This value is temporary
]; > the element is freed here, it no longer exists!
```

You then try to create a `HtmlRewriter` using a non-existent value!

```rust
Settings {
    element_content_handlers: handlers,
    // the element inside of `handlers` doesn't exist anymore!
    ..Settings::default()
},
```

Obviously, the borrow checker catches this issue, and your code doesn't compile.

The solution here is to bind that element to a variable with `let`:

```rust
let element = element!("a[href]", |el| {
    let href = el.get_attribute("href").unwrap().replace("http:", "https:");
    el.set_attribute("href", &href).unwrap();
    Ok(())
});
```

And then create the vector:

```rust
let handlers = vec![element];
```

Now, the value is bound to a variable (`element`), and so it lives long enough to be borrowed later in `HtmlRewriter::try_new`

Comment: Your solution was proposed by the compiler, but what if I have a lot of elements? I would like to avoid naming 50 elements for example. Is there a way to do this without binding all the elements? Also why it ends there in case of a let binding, but not when I put the vector inside newly constructed struct passed to a method?

Comment: I mentioned the second question in the answer, but to make it clear I added part of this comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you create something, it gets bound to the innermost scope possible for the purposes of tracking its lifetime. Using a `let` binding at a higher scope binds the value to that scope, making its lifetime longer. If you're creating a lot of things, then applying an operation to them (for example, passing them to another function), it often makes sense to create a vector of values and then apply a transformation to them instead. As an example,

```rust
let xs = (0..10).map(|n| SomeStruct { n }).map(|s| another_function(s)).collect();
```

This way you don't need to bind the `SomeStruct` objects to anything explicitly.

Comment: Why, if it's innermost scope, it's different for `let hs = vec![elements!(...), ...]` and different for `try_new(handlers: vec![elements!(...), ...]`? For both expressions innermost scope is vec![] scope. I intend to have multiple elements and then dynamically add more to the vec before passing the vec to `try_new`.

Comment: In the first case you're binding the result of the vec macro to a name in the outer scope. In the second you're ephemerally generating a vector within the try_new call.

Comment: Is there a way to have specific elements in vec and: not to name them, not to push to the vec? So how can I put the vec outside to do things with it before passing it to try_new, while avoiding binding all elements, because I don't want to name them.

Comment: The best way is probably to take whatever's generating the elements and package it as an `Iterator`, do any intermediate steps you might need with functions like `map` and `filter`, and then `collect` it into a vector at the end (similar to the simple example already present in the answer).

Comment: My problem is that I have multiple elements that I create manually in code. Also between this step and giving it out to try_new I would like to extend the vec with additional "generated" elements. So in pseudo code: `let mut handlers = vec![
element!("a", |el| {...}), element!("img", |el| {...}), element!("video", |el| {...}), ...20 more
];
for ... { ...
handlers.push(elem);
}
try_new(handlers);`
At this stage I'll probably go with binding all the elements first, but it's _annoying_, because  I will have to name them and any change will have then two places. It seems like a limitation.

Comment: You don't need to bind everything individually. You can use the `extend` function of vectors to add another vector onto the end of your first one.